# How to detect back button -vs- GoBack() in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, navigation, assemblies

Maybe I'm over-thinking this, but here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have two MVVM projects (assemblies) in my WP7 app.  One page in the main project will call another page in the second project.  The second page will allow the user to browse through a list of files on the web and select one to be downloaded to Isolated Storage.  The files are rather small.

For a little background: I want two assemblies because this file-selection feature is not used often in the app and I want the Main assembly to be as small as possible to decrease startup time.  I also want to be able to re-use this file-selection/download component in other apps.

The simple thing I'm trying to figure out is that when the user selects the file and it is downloaded, I will execute a GoBack() to return to the calling page.  On the calling page, I need to know if, in fact, the user downloaded a file or if they cancelled out of the operation by simply hitting the back button.  I thought the obvious thing might be to just check for the existence of the file in Isolated storage, but that just feel like a bit of a kludge to me.

I also thought about the Messenger, but I'm not sure how that would work across two assemblies.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is tough to know without looking at the code. However, I would suggest that you could pass back a value to the page depending on whether you successfully downloaded your file. Navigate with the value as follows (pass true or false depending on download success):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(("/Page.xaml?download=true", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then evaluate the page in the destination as follows:

```
string download = "";
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("download", out imageurl))
{
}
```

Comment: GoBack() and Navigate() are different, if you use Navigate to go the previous page you will also need to remove it from the navigation journal or otherwise when you hit back you will get to the wrong page. But otherwise the solution above should work. So make sure you call NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry after Navigate()

Comment: Thanks all.  Yes, Vitalij, I wanted to use GoBack in my page because I don't want to code in a dependency as to where to go-back to.  In other words, I'm trying to create a reusable page that can be used in other projects.  Therefore I wont know where to go back to.  I suppose I could capture where I came from in the OnNavigatedTo override and then return there using Navigate.  And I would have to remember to RemoveBackEntry on the original calling page.  So...while I know I can do this...is it the *right* thing to do?